# Make runs target with variable name regardless of whether file exists

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU make to work with some data. When I try to run a target with a variable name, make will run that target, *regardless of whether the target file already exists*. Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
include config.mk

.PHONY : all
all : $(PG_DB).db

$(PG_DB).db : 
    createdb $(PG_DB) -U $(PG_USER)
    touch $@
```

where config.mk contains:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables
SHELL := bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -eu -o pipefail
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.SUFFIXES:

PG_USER="foo"
PG_DB="foo"
```

When I run `make`, make creates the Postgres database, and then touches the file `foo.db`. However, when I run `make` again, the output is:

```
createdb "foo" -U foo
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: database "foo" already exists
make : *** ["foo".db] Error 1
```

This shouldn't have happened! I would expect `make`, in this situation, to check the prerequisites for the phony target `all`, see that `foo.db` already exists, and exit immediately without doing anything.

Strangely, this is exactly what happens when I get rid of the variables in the target names:

```
include config.mk

.PHONY : all
all : foo.db

foo.db :
    createdb $(PG_DB) -U $(PG_USER)
    touch $@
```

When I run `make` with this modified `Makefile`, I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all`.
```

Which is exactly what I expect.

What's going on here?

Comment: Include the output from running `make -rRd` in the variable failure case? Also what version of make is this? 4.0? 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not come from the variable, it comes from the quotation mark in the variable value. `make` does not remove the quotation mark before checking the dependency. So it is checking for the file `"foo".db` with the quotation mark included. While the command `touch "foo".db` gets interpreted by the `shell` that removes the quotation marks. So for `make`, the file will never be there and you will always have the same problem. When you put the dependency explicitly, you put it as `foo.db` that does not include the quotation mark. It makes all the difference.

in config.mk, turn

```
PG_DB="foo"
```

into

```
PG_DB=foo
```

it should work. I guess createdb is a normal shell command that will not care about the quotation marks. Otherwise you will need to add it before calling the command.

Comment: Thanks! This was it. I didn't realize that the quotes around values in Makefiles are always interpreted as literals.